# How to modify a file's dirname/path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have an array called `ArrayHT` of xml docs. I want to search in that array for a particular xml document by the full path, but one part of the path needs to changed before searching.

My setup:

```
ArrayID.each do |file| #loops through all elements of ArrayID
  id_filepath = File.path(file) #creates id_filepath variable that contains the full filepath of the file/element currently in the loop
  # => "/some/path/ht/name/doc.xml"
end
```

**Problem**: At this point I want to take the `id_filepath` variable and change `ht` to `id` and then I execute the following to find if the modified `id_filepath` exists in the `ArrayHT` array:

```
ht_filepath = ArrayHT.find { |e| e.match(id_filepath) } #searches another array, ArrayHT for the file
```

How best to do address the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the answer:

`ht_filepath = id_filepath.sub /ht/, 'id'`

Comment: Safer way: `ht_filepath = id_filepath.sub '/ht/', '/id/'`

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev